# JavaScript Inner Functions & 'this'

Tags: javascript, function, scope, this

In my understanding, it is not until an object invokes a Function that **this** is actually assigned a value. And the value it is assigned is based exclusively on the object that invokes the Function.

Also, the scope chain rule in JS is LEG.

So, in (strict mode):

```
function one () {
    var a = 2;
    function two () {
        console.log(a)};
    two()
}

one() // output 2
```

But:

```
function one () {
    var a = 2;
    function two () {
        console.log(this.a)};
    two()
}

one()  //output undefined
```

It was my understandig functions were objects, and in the previous invokation the function object **one** would be the making the call of **two**, which translates **this.a** into **one.a**. Obviously that is not the case.

Also:

```
function one () {
        var a = 2}

console.log(one.a)  //outputs undefined
```

Any clarification about what is happening would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `one.a` does not refer to a local variable in `one`. That's not how local variables work.

Comment: The way you place those closing braces is painful on my eyes. Also, what is LEG?

Comment: `two.call( {a} );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function one () {
    var a = 2;
    function two () {
        console.log(this.a)};
    two()
}

one()  //output undefined
```

Here you are calling both `one` and `two` as functions on their own, not as properties of some object (e.g. `someObject.one()`). This means that `this` will refer to the global scope (or to `undefined` if the code is in strict mode). The `a` property of your global scope is `undefined`, so that's why you see `undefined`. Calling `two()` inside of `one()` doesn't make it so that `this` refers to `one`.

```
function one () {
        var a = 2}

console.log(one.a)  //outputs undefined
```

`a` is not a property of `one`. It is a variable *inside it*. A property of `one` would look like this.

```js
function one() {
}
one.a = 7;

console.log(one.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are treating a regular function as a class object. You only call one() but you do not actually instantiate a new One() object.

Answer (score 0):

***Scope*** and ***Context*** are different concepts. Within a JS-Function scope one can address any value that either got assigned inside a function or any value that got assigned outside such a function as long as this function itself is a member of the outer scope. In addition, as long as a function does not create a closure, ***scope* gets created** just at a function's call time. *Context* is addressable too. But unlike *scope*, ***context* gets evaluated** at a functions call time. Thus `this` is just a placeholder for *context* that can vary from one time calling a function to another.

```js
function contextAwareMethod(injectedValue) {
  "use strict";
  var
    context         = this, // dynamically evaluated.
    innerScopeValue = "created at a functions call time";

  console.log('dynamically evaluated context : ', context);

  console.log('this.contextValue : ', (context && context.value));
  console.log('innerScopeValue : ', innerScopeValue);
  console.log('injectedValue : ', injectedValue);  
}

console.log('"case A"');
contextAwareMethod('argument A');
console.log('\n');

console.log('"case B"');
contextAwareMethod.call({ value: "conext B"});
console.log('\n');

console.log('"case C"');
contextAwareMethod.call({ value: "conext C"}, 'argument C');
console.log('\n');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```